# Verificar e alterar atributos de uma coluna a partir de uma lista com R

Tags: r, data.frame

Preciso substituir os dados de uma coluna em uma tabela se eles não estiverem contidos numa lista especificada pela string "Não Informado"

Tentei esse comando:

```
jan_mar$Bairro[which(!(bairros_cidade)] = "Não Informado"
```

Também tentei:

```
jan_mar$Bairro[jan_mar$Bairro != bairros_cidade] = "Não Identificado"
```

Com este ultimo comando a resposta foi:
"Warning message:
In jan_mar$Bairro != bairros_cidade :
comprimento do objeto maior não é múltiplo do comprimento do objeto menor"

E o valor retornado de "Não Informado" foi de 15112, muito acima dos 795 obtidos a partir do calculo manual das inconsistências

Com nenhuma deles obtive o resultado desejado

```
library(xlsx)
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

cursor1 = read.xlsx("Estácio - Vacinação COVID Jaraguá do Sul - Jan a Mar.2021.xlsx", sheetIndex = 1)
cursor2 = read.xlsx("Estácio - Vacinação COVID Jaraguá do Sul - Jan a Mar.2021.xlsx", sheetIndex = 2)

jan_mar = merge.data.frame(cursor1, cursor2, all = TRUE)

bairros_cidade = c("Agua Verde", "Aguas Claras", "Amizade", "Barra do Rio Cerro", "Barra do Rio Molha", "Boa Vista", 
                   "Braço do Ribeirão Cavalo", "Centenario", "Centro", "Chico de Paulo", "Czerniewicz", "Estrada Nova",
                   "Ilha da Figueira", "Jaragua 84", "Jaragua 99", "Jaragua Esquerdo", "João Pessoa", "Nereu Ramos",
                   "Nova Brasilia", "Parque Malwee", "Rau", "Ribeirão Cavalo", "Rio Cerro I", "Rio Cerro II",
                   "Rio da Luz", "Rio Molha", "Santa Luzia", "Santo Antonio", "São Luis", "Tifa Martins", "Tifa Monos",
                    "Tres Rios do Norte", "Tres Rios do Sul", "Vieira", "Vila Baependi", "Vila Lalau", "Vila Lenzi",
                   "Vila Nova")


jan_mar$Bairro[which(!(bairros_cidade)] = "Não Informado"

jan_mar$Bairro[jan_mar$Bairro != bairros_cidade] = "Não Identificado"

table(jan_mar$Bairro)
```

Answer (score 2):

Como não incluiu uma amostra dos seus dados, vou usar exemplos genéricos.

R é voltado para operações vetoriais. O operador `==` atua elemento a elemento:

```
a <- 1:3
b <- 3:1

a == b
#> [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

No caso de vetores com comprimentos diferentes, o resultado será um vetor lógico com o maior comprimento. Se o comprimento menor for múltiplo do maior, será reciclado. Se não, retornará FALSE para as posições sem equivalente, juntamente com um aviso:

```
c <- c(1,2,1,3)
d <- 1:2

c == d
#> [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE

c == a
#> [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
#> Warning message:
#> In c == a : longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Para comparar se os elementos de um vetor estão inclusos entre os elementos de outro, independente de posição, use o operador `%in%`:

```
x <- LETTERS[1:5]
y <- LETTERS[2:3]

x %in% y
#> [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE

x[!x %in% y] <- "X"

x
#> [1] "X" "B" "C" "X" "X"
```

No seu caso:

```
jan_mar$Bairro[!jan_mar$Bairro %in% bairros_cidade] <- "Não Informado"
```